# $lookup returning empty array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a students collection and a classes collection
student._id(ObjectId) needs to match in a lookup of the files collection on classes.owner(String). I am getting empty array for files. What am I doing wrong?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Account = require('../models/account');
var Connections = require('../models/connections');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


//get all advocates for student.
router.route('/:student_id?')

  .get(function (req, res) {

    Account.aggregate(
      { "$match": { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.student_id) } },
      {$lookup:
        {
          from: 'classes',
          localField: 'owner',//**String**
          foreignField: '_id', //**ObjectId**
          as: 'classes'
        }
      }       
    ).exec(function (err, doc) {
        console.log(doc[0]);
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        } else {
          res.send(doc[0]).end();
        }
      })
  });


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Post your schemas. And `_id: req.params.student_id` is sufficient.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the lookup. You cannot match a local field that is of ObjectId to a foreignField of String. Anyway around this?

Comment: Yes.. change classes owner to an ObjectId. Why are you using a String?

Comment: I can easily do that but the problem is is in order to make that ID usable on the front end aren't I going to have to parse it all over the place? Like convert it to a string every time I need to reference it? Or does mongoose automatically return it as a string before sending it back to the UI?

Comment: Oh and the other problem is is how I'm I going to save owner as an object ID never I'm adding a new entry? Because the UI will be passing it back as a string from the API calls. Do I need to declare it as an object id my model or something?

Comment: Don't worry about the conversions, mongoose will handle it. Just treat it as if you were getting or setting a string.

Comment: So my code should work if I change all to object ids? Also will I only pull records where there is a match on owner=_id?

Answer (score 4):

check you from clause, is it your collection name? I used schema name instead of the collection name which results in empty result.

```
{$lookup:
        {
          from: 'classes',  //check this
          localField: 'owner',//**String**
          foreignField: '_id', //**ObjectId**
          as: 'classes'
        }
      }
```